# Newbie: convert input from getch() into an int

Tags: c

```
// get user's input
int ch = getch();

switch (ch)
    {
        //input a number
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':
            {

            int i = atoi(ch);

            g.board[g.y][g.x] = i;

            }
}
```

In the code I was given to add on to, ch was declared as an int.  However, the function getch saves input as a string, correct?  How can I convert the string ch into an int so I can work with it?  I tried to use the atoi() function, but I keep getting these error messages.

```
sudoku.c: In function 'main':
sudoku.c:247:17: error: passing argument 1 of 'atoi' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]
/usr/include/stdlib.h:148:12: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'int'
sudoku.c:252:17: error: expected ';' before 'g'
sudoku.c:244:21: error: unused variable 'y' [-Werror=unused-variable]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> the function getch saves input as a string, correct?

No, `getch` reads a character and returns an int (you did correctly define `ch` as `int`). The easiest way to convert it to a real integer is to subtract `'0'`. So after validating `getch`, you can replace most of your code with:

```
if (isdigit(ch))
    g.board[g.y][g.x] = ch - '0';
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
int i = (int)((char)ch - '0');
```

The numbers 0-9 are laid out in ascending order in terms of character codes.  Hence subtracting '0' from the `char` value will produce an offset that is equal to the actual number in question

Comment: The "atoi()" function expects a string (not a character).  Hence the warning.  "Subtract character - '0'" is an elegant solution: I'd go for it.  FINALLY: any reason you're not including "0" in your list of valid characters?  Any chance you might need a "10", or an "11", or "1000" someday?

Comment: @paulsm4 did you meaon to add this comment to the question?

Answer (score 1):

`atoi` expects a C-string (a `\0`/nul terminated string). In your example you are passing it a single character.

Instead, utilize the benefits of the ASCII table layout:

```
/* Assuming (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') */
int value = ch - '0';
/* Borrows from the fact that the characters '0' through '9' are laid
   out sequentially in the ASCII table. Simple subtraction allows you to 
   glean their number value.
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

just subtract with '0' and it will automatically become an integer. The x is your variable

```
 int x;
 x=getch()-'0';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
        int i = atoi(ch);
```

replace this code below

```
int i = atoi((const char *)&ch);
```

you can find this with manual (Linux)

```
# man atoi
```

prototype is

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int atoi(const char *nptr);
```

Comment: `ch` is not going to be a valid pointer. This is going to cause a crash.